# ¿Como utilizar AsyncTask para un List<> en Android Studio?

Tags: android, lista, asynctask

soy nuevo en la programacion de Android y es esta plataforma, y tengo una duda de como usar el AsyncTask, que en este caso quisiera que mi lista se cargue en segundo plano ya que lo tengo en un activity, como una pantalla de cargado y cuando quiero pasar de una actividad a esta se queda en negro cuando carga los datos, asi es como lo tengo como metodo:

```
 public List<Plantas> listarPlantas() {
    List<Plantas> plantas = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Connection conn = SyncSQLServer.ConexionBD();
        if (conn != null) {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.setQueryTimeout(50);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from Plantas");
            while (rs.next()) {
                plantas.add(new Plantas(rs.getString("nombre"),
                        rs.getString("temperatura"),
                        rs.getString("humedad"),
                        rs.getString("riego"),
                        rs.getString("descripcion"),
                        R.drawable.planta_brujas));
            }
            conn.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error!!! Conexión fallida.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return plantas;
}
```

Asi es como cargo los datos en la interfaz:

```
rvPlantas = findViewById(R.id.recyclerPlantas);
    rvPlantas.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    adaptadorPlantas = new RecyclerViewAdaptador(listarPlantas());
    rvPlantas.setAdapter(adaptadorPlantas);

    if (adaptadorPlantas.listaPlantas.size() > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Datos cargados.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error!!! No se pudo obtener la lista.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Intente hacerlo pero la verdad no entiendo como funciona exactamente, por lo que quiero que los datos se carguen como en segundo plano, asi como el progress bar, pero me interesa mas que cargara la lista.
Agradeceria mucho su apoyo y comprension.

Comment: Puedes colocar el codigo del adaptador? para ver como estas seteando los datos del item de la lista.

Comment: Sea donde sea, en un AsyncTask, o cómo sea, dado que el adaptador es el que guarda la lista de elementos a mostrar, cada vez que cambies la lista, se la tienes que volver a pasar al adaptador y llamar a notifyDataSetChanged del adaptador para que vuelva a repintar los datos.

Answer (score 0):

Este es mi clase del adaptador, tengo entendido que aqui es donde se cargan los datos junto con los copntroles de la actividad principal:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.inginfo.asistentederiego.R;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdaptador.ViewHolder> {

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView nombre, riego, temperatura, humedad, descripcion;
    private ImageView viewPlanta;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombreP);
        riego = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRiego);
        temperatura = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTemperatura);
        humedad = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHumedad);
        descripcion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescripcion);
        viewPlanta = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlanta);
    }
}

public List<Plantas> listaPlantas;

public RecyclerViewAdaptador(List<Plantas> listaPlantas) {
    this.listaPlantas = listaPlantas;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_plantas,parent,false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    viewHolder.nombre.setText(listaPlantas.get(i).getNombre());
    viewHolder.temperatura.setText("Temperatura: "+listaPlantas.get(i).getTemperatura()+"°C");
    viewHolder.humedad.setText("Humedad: "+listaPlantas.get(i).getHumedad()+"%");
    viewHolder.riego.setText("Riego: "+listaPlantas.get(i).getRiego());
    viewHolder.descripcion.setText("Descripción: "+listaPlantas.get(i).getDescripcion());
    viewHolder.viewPlanta.setImageResource(listaPlantas.get(i).getImgPlanta());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listaPlantas.size();
}
```

}